# Abnormal behavior in apache load balancing

Tags: apache, load-balancing

I have a apache mod proxy load balancer with the following configuration 
`NameVirtualHost *:5555 
<VirtualHost *:5555> 
    ServerName localhost
    ProxyPass / balancer://dgraphs/ 
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://dgraphs/ 
    <Proxy balancer://dgraphs> 
        BalancerMember http://172.16.23.232:15000 loadfactor=1
        BalancerMember http://172.16.27.87:15011 loadfactor=1 
    </Proxy> 
</VirtualHost>
<Location /balancer-manager> 
    SetHandler balancer-manager 
</Location>`

I am getting an abnormal behavior in how apache load balancer is forwarding the query request to the balancer-members. Each Time I send a request to apache, it is sending 3 requests to the balancer members, one to one server and two to the other. On successive request this gets reversed, I mean to say it then sends Two request to the first server and one to the second. Heres' the snapshot of the balancer-member handler.

[Request 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B39N8ztL-yN3RHpzcklJb0pnSUE/view?usp=sharing)

[Request 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B39N8ztL-yN3WHd3QVZRd0N0WjA/view?usp=sharing)

and this behaiviour repeats(+2+1, +1+2)

Am I doning something wrong in the configuration or is there some kind of a delay because of which apache failsover and send request to second server and again to first server everytime?
Please HElP!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you maybe missing some configuration details of the Virtual Host with Load Balancer setup, below is a sample configuration that works:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyRequests off

ServerName servername.local

<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
        # TomcatA
        BalancerMember http://172.20.20.101:8080 route=tomcatA
        # TomcatB
        BalancerMember http://172.20.20.102:8080 route=tomcatB
        # TomcatC
        BalancerMember http://172.20.20.103:8080 route=tomcatC


        # Security – to determine who is allowed to access
        # Currently all are allowed to access
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from none
        Allow from all

        # Load Balancer Settings
        # We will be configuring a simple Round
        # Robin style load balancer.  This means
        # that all nodes take an equal share of
        # of the load.
        ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests

</Proxy>

# balancer-manager
# This tool is built into the mod_proxy_balancer
# module and will allow you to do some simple
# modifications to the balanced group via a gui
# web interface.
<Location /balancer-manager>
        SetHandler balancer-manager

        # I recommend locking this one down to your
        # administering location
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Location>

# Point of Balance
# This setting will allow to explicitly name the
# location in the site that we want to be
# balanced, in this example we will balance "/"
# or everything in the site.
ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid nofailover=Off scolonpathdelim=On
```

If you require sharing sessions between the App Servers instances further configuration will be needed to be done on Apache to use AJP port instead of HTTP as well as configuring the app servers to share the sessions. You may get further details here:

[Load Balancing: Apache versus Physical Appliance](http://bigthinkingapplied.com/load-balancing-apache-versus-ip-based/)